# Via github api or git is there away to differentiate between a commit that was simply rebased onto of master vs a new commit?

Tags: git, github

I have a webhook that should respond differently in response to the two events 
- A developer pushes a new commit to their branch
- A developer rebases their branch on top of master (no additional code changes)

Is there a way with either git or the github api to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not any that I can think of. There's nothing flagging a rebase or cherry-picked revisions. You might take a look at commit and author date. If they are different, you might be in front of a cherry-picked revision or a rebase. But you might get false positives if anyone has amended a revision.